# android espresso test webview wechat

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am writing tests for wechat app(a third part app), below is my test code and the error I get: *No activity found*.
How can I create an third part app activity?

Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Error:

```
No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?
```

Test Code:

```
public void testHelloWorldOnView() {
    try {
        Context context=getInstrumentation().getContext();
        PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.tencent.mm");
        if (i == null) {
            //throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
        }
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        context.startActivity(i);
        ViewInteraction view=onView(withText("通讯录"));
        view.perform(click());

 }
}
```

Comment: your question is unclear. please add whole test class to see config

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(
        MainActivity.class, true, true) {
};
```

Make sure Its true for both the parameters.